# 信息 vs 資訊: what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, difference, word

I asked ChatGPT and I got the following response, is this correct?

"信息" (information) has a broader and more general use about being data/facts/information, while "资讯" (news) is more about the dissemination of news or the latest updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

资讯 is similar to 新闻 (news), in fact 新闻资讯 is often used as a whole. It's a short piece of text that conveys information to people.

信息 can refer to all kinds of information, like 身份信息 (identity information), 行情信息 (market trend information), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both 信息 and 资讯 mean information, but the former is an abstract concept that refers to something/event that carries a central message to inform the recipient; the latter is a collection of knowledge/data on something/field, such as 新闻,消息,情报, for the uses of the recipient.